# Convert an Xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml is as follows which i wan to convert to the xml below using xslt :

```
       <items>
            <item id='10' name='item1'>
                 <atm id ='15' value='xxx'/>
            </item>

            <!-- this should not have the atm node displayed in the outptut -->
            <item id='11' name='item2'> 
                 <atm id ='16' value='yyyy'/>
            </item>
            <!-- this should not have the atm node displayed in the outptut -->
            <item id='11' name='item3'>
                 <atm id ='17' value='yyyy'/>
            </item>
       </items>
```

I want to display the atm node values only for the items whose item id!='11' so the output should be :

```
 <items>
            <item id='10' name='item1'>
            <atm id ='15' value='xxx'/>
            </item>
            <item id='11' name='item2'/>
            <item id='11' name='item3'/>
 </items>
```

so i wouldn't want the atm child nodes to display for the items which have a id='11'
would appretiate your help thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i wouldn't want the atm child nodes to display for the items which
>   have a id='11'

So just copy everything as is, and suppress the nodes you do not want by matching them with a template that outputs nothing:

*XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="atm[../@id='11']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which in your example would yield:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item id="10" name="item1">
      <atm id="15" value="xxx"/>
   </item>
   <item id="11" name="item2"/>
   <item id="11" name="item3"/>
</items>
```